# Why is my query load slower than normal queries

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a perfect explanation why my query tends to load slows as to 100secs?

Is there any possible reconstruction to make my query load faster?

```
    SELECT IF(IMI.BRANCH_CODE IS NOT NULL AND IMI.PRODCODE IS NOT NULL AND IMI.POLNO IS NOT NULL,"Y","N") as STATUS,
                        NOW(),ICH.CLAIM_NO,ICH.BRANCH_CODE,
                        ICH.PRODUCT_TYPE,ICH.POLICY_NO,ICH.ASSURED_NAME,
                        ICH.AGENT_NO,ICH.INCEPTION_DT,ICH.EXPIRY_DT,
                        ICH.DT_REPORTED,IMI.BASIC_PREMIUM,ICH.CLAIM_STATUS,
                        IRPD.CLAIM_RESERVE,IRPD.TOTAL_AMT_RECOMMENDED,IRPD.DT_RECOMMENDED,
                        IMI.UW_YEAR,ICDO.PLATE_NO,ICDO.CHASSIS_NO,
                        ICDO.MOTOR_NO,IMI.LOCATION,IMI.RISKNO,IMI.SEQNO
                    FROM `ICATS_CLAIM_HEADER` ICH  
                    LEFT JOIN `ICATS_CLAIM_DETAILS_OD` ICDO ON ICH.CLAIM_NO = ICDO.CLAIM_NO
                    LEFT JOIN `ICATS_MULTIPLE_LOSS` IML ON ICH.CLAIM_NO = IML.CLAIM_NO
                    LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM ICATS_RESERVE_PAYMENT_DETAILS 
                                WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(),DT_RECOMMENDED)=1 OR DATEDIFF(NOW(),RESERVE_DT)=1) IRPD 
                                ON ICH.CLAIM_NO = IRPD.CLAIM_NO
                    LEFT JOIN (SELECT POLNO,PRODCODE,BRANCH_CODE,MAX(SEQNO)as SEQNO FROM IWRITE_MOTOR_INFO 
                                GROUP BY POLNO,PRODCODE,BRANCH_CODE) IM 
                                ON ICH.POLICY_NO = IM.POLNO AND ICH.BRANCH_CODE = IM.BRANCH_CODE AND ICH.PRODUCT_TYPE = IM.PRODCODE 
                                JOIN IWRITE_MOTOR_INFO IMI 
                                ON IM.POLNO = IMI.POLNO AND IM.PRODCODE = IMI.PRODCODE AND IM.BRANCH_CODE = IMI.BRANCH_CODE AND IM.SEQNO = IMI.SEQNO
                    WHERE (DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),ICH.CLAIM_STATUS_DT)=1
                            OR DATEDIFF(NOW(),ICDO.TRANSACTION_DT)=1
                            OR DATEDIFF(NOW(),IRPD.RESERVE_DT)=1
                            OR DATEDIFF(NOW(),IRPD.DT_RECOMMENDED)=1)
                ORDER BY ICH.CLAIM_NO,IRPD.SEQUENCE_NO ASC
```

In overall here is my whole query.Just the fact that while checking all the datas to be inserted my query seems to load slow as to 100secs.

```
INSERT INTO `ICATS_IINSURE_CLAIM_HEADER`(IINSURE_EXIST,RECORD_CREATED_DT,CLAIM_NUMBER,BRANCH_CODE,PRODCODE,POLNO,ASSURED_NAME1,
                AGENT_CODE,INCEPTION,EXPIRY,DATE_REPORTED,BASIC_PREMIUM,
                CLAIM_STATUS,RESERVE_AMOUNT,CLAIMS_PAID_AMOUNT,
                DATE_RECOMMEND_PAYMENT,UW_YEAR,PLATE_NUMBER,
                CHASSIS,ENGINE,LOCATION,RISKNO,SEQ)
            SELECT IF(IMI.BRANCH_CODE IS NOT NULL AND IMI.PRODCODE IS NOT NULL AND IMI.POLNO IS NOT NULL,"Y","N") as STATUS,
                NOW(),ICH.CLAIM_NO,ICH.BRANCH_CODE,
                ICH.PRODUCT_TYPE,ICH.POLICY_NO,ICH.ASSURED_NAME,
                ICH.AGENT_NO,ICH.INCEPTION_DT,ICH.EXPIRY_DT,
                ICH.DT_REPORTED,IMI.BASIC_PREMIUM,ICH.CLAIM_STATUS,
                IRPD.CLAIM_RESERVE,IRPD.TOTAL_AMT_RECOMMENDED,IRPD.DT_RECOMMENDED,
                IMI.UW_YEAR,ICDO.PLATE_NO,ICDO.CHASSIS_NO,
                ICDO.MOTOR_NO,IMI.LOCATION,IMI.RISKNO,IMI.SEQNO
            FROM `ICATS_CLAIM_HEADER` ICH  
            LEFT JOIN `ICATS_CLAIM_DETAILS_OD` ICDO ON ICH.CLAIM_NO = ICDO.CLAIM_NO
            LEFT JOIN `ICATS_MULTIPLE_LOSS` IML ON ICH.CLAIM_NO = IML.CLAIM_NO
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM ICATS_RESERVE_PAYMENT_DETAILS 
                        WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(),DT_RECOMMENDED)=1 OR DATEDIFF(NOW(),RESERVE_DT)=1) IRPD 
                        ON ICH.CLAIM_NO = IRPD.CLAIM_NO
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT POLNO,PRODCODE,BRANCH_CODE,MAX(SEQNO)as SEQNO FROM IWRITE_MOTOR_INFO 
                        GROUP BY POLNO,PRODCODE,BRANCH_CODE) IM 
                        ON ICH.POLICY_NO = IM.POLNO AND ICH.BRANCH_CODE = IM.BRANCH_CODE AND ICH.PRODUCT_TYPE = IM.PRODCODE 
                        JOIN IWRITE_MOTOR_INFO IMI 
                        ON IM.POLNO = IMI.POLNO AND IM.PRODCODE = IMI.PRODCODE AND IM.BRANCH_CODE = IMI.BRANCH_CODE AND IM.SEQNO = IMI.SEQNO
            WHERE (DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),ICH.CLAIM_STATUS_DT)=1
                    OR DATEDIFF(NOW(),ICDO.TRANSACTION_DT)=1
                    OR DATEDIFF(NOW(),IRPD.RESERVE_DT)=1
                    OR DATEDIFF(NOW(),IRPD.DT_RECOMMENDED)=1)
        ORDER BY ICH.CLAIM_NO,IRPD.SEQUENCE_NO ASC
```

Comment: try avoid using inner selects (I can see some in your `left join`)

Comment: ORs are notorious for poor performance

Comment: @SNpn, I've seen performance improve by selecting from subqueries instead of the actual tables.

Comment: @SNpn I tend to use inner selects just to join specific datas neededed.If not some datas would be possibly duplicated since my data ratio from other table is 1:MANY from that table.. that will affect my expected results using my where clause..

Comment: You're doing ORs where each OR condition is a different table reference. Have you tried doing a UNION ALL and comparing the results and the performance?

Comment: @OMG Ponies how much % did where clause affects query execution?Am i wrong if I think that if it is index properly it will lower the risk of slow execution?

Comment: @JasonWhisman I think having my where condition in different tables is not the issue here if they are indexed very well. Am i right?

Comment: I've seen it make a difference, although more often in SQL Server than MySQL.  The UNION ALLs may also give you the option to structure your joins different, but only if, for instance, you don't expect data in both `ICDO` and `IRPD` for the same `ICH` row.

Comment: @JasonWhisman I think using LEFT JOIN is much better than UNION.Because I read that each SELECT statement within the UNION must have the same number of columns. The columns must also have similar data types. Also, the columns in each SELECT statement must be in the same order. Is this right?

Comment: You are correct about how the `SELECT` portion of the statements must be structured the same, so your code is more verbose (and uglier-looking) for the same results. What a `UNION ALL` gains for you is some flexibility in your `FROM..JOIN` and `WHERE`.

Answer (score 3):

I think one of the most signifcant reason is that your where clause has nothing but functions.  To fix this, find a way to introduce variables so that this:

```
WHERE (DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),ICH.CLAIM_STATUS_DT)=1
OR DATEDIFF(NOW(),ICDO.TRANSACTION_DT)=1
OR DATEDIFF(NOW(),IRPD.RESERVE_DT)=1
OR DATEDIFF(NOW(),IRPD.DT_RECOMMENDED)=1)
```

becomes something like this;

```
where ich.claim_status_dt >= a variable 
and ich.claim_status_dt < another variable
etc
```

You can make this a stored procedure and set up the variables there, or, if this query is part of a php/.net/coldfusion/whatever application, set up the variables in the application code and convert them to parameters.